# What's the point of the prefix line in conda environment file when creating a new environment?

Tags: python, conda, virtual-environment

To save a conda environment and re-create it, I use:

```
# Save the environment
conda env export > my_conda_env.yml

# Re-create the environment
conda env create --file my_conda_env.yml

# Reactivate the environment
conda activate pytorch
```

I notice that `my_conda_env.yml` contains `prefix: /home/franck/anaconda3/envs/pytorch` on the last line. What's the point of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It specifies the directory to put the environment in.

Straight from the [documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#specifying-a-location-for-an-environment):

> You can control where a conda environment lives by providing a path to
> a target directory when creating the environment. For example, the
> following command will create a new environment in a subdirectory of
> the current working directory called envs:
>
> ```
> conda create --prefix ./envs jupyterlab=0.35 matplotlib=3.1 numpy=1.16
> ```

Or, you could have checked:

```
conda env create --help
```

And it shows:

```
  -p PATH, --prefix PATH
                        Full path to environment location (i.e. prefix).
```